# Program not working

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

I am trying to write a program to calculate the profit made by selling a car. My output is not coming out with the right number. I do not think I am using the proper format specifier. I keep getting a number that is not what I should be getting.

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        int main()
        {
           char model;
           double purchase;
           double sell;
           double profit;
           printf("Car Profit Calculator\n");

           printf("Enter Car Model\n");
           scanf("%u",&model);
           printf("Enter Purchase Price\n");
           scanf("%d",&purchase);
           printf("Enter Price Sold for\n");
           scanf("%d",&sell);
           profit = (double)sell / purchase;
           printf("Profit%d\n", profit);
           return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Did it  not occur to you to Google 'printf format specifiers'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're using wrong conversion specifier. for a `char`, you should use `%c`, for a double, you've to use `%lf`.

From `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2, `fscanf()` function definition,

> *..[..]..* Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

So, you're facing [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In your code, change

```
scanf("%u",&model);
```

to

```
scanf("%c",&model);
```

and

```
scanf("%d",&purchase);
```

to

```
scanf("%lf",&purchase);
```

same for `sell` also

and lastly,

```
 printf("Profit%d\n", profit);
```

to

```
  printf("Profit %f\n", profit);  //for printf, %f is enough for a double
```

Comment: I keep getting 0 for my profit.

Comment: Also how do I get it to take a letter name for the model and not just a number?

Comment: @werty345353534 yeah, the result of UB can be anything.

Comment: @werty345353534 `%c` conversion specifier takes a _char_ (letter).

Comment: The problem is if I enter a letter the program just ends.

Comment: How would I make this into a loop that would allow me to calculate multiple cars at once?

Comment: @werty345353534 well, after _all_ the changes , [it works fine, see here](http://ideone.com/01xO7q)

Comment: @werty345353534 aah.. to use this in a loop, you've to use `scanf(" %c",&model);`, mind the _space_ before `%c`, which will _eat up_ the previously stored `\n`(newline).